# NHibernate query against the key field of a dictionary (map)

Tags: nhibernate

I have an object model where a Calendar object has an `IDictionary<MembershipUser, Perms>` called UserPermissions, where MembershipUser is an object, and Perms is a simple enumeration.  This is in the mapping file for Calendar as

```
<map name="UserPermissions" table="CalendarUserPermissions" lazy="true" cascade="all">
  <key column="CalendarID"/>
  <index-many-to-many class="MembershipUser" column="UserGUID" />
  <element column="Permissions" type="CalendarPermission" not-null="true" />
</map>
```

Now I want to execute a query to find all calendars for which a given user has some permission defined.  The permission is irrelevant; I just want a list of the calendars where a given user is present as a key in the UserPermissions dictionary.  I have the username property, not a `MembershipUser` object.  How do I build that using QBC (or HQL)?  Here's what I've tried:

```
ISession session = SessionManager.CurrentSession;
ICriteria calCrit = session.CreateCriteria<Calendar>();
ICriteria userCrit = calCrit.CreateCriteria("UserPermissions.indices");
userCrit.Add(Expression.Eq("Username", username));
return calCrit.List<Calendar>();
```

This constructed invalid SQL -- the WHERE clause contained `WHERE membership1_.Username = @p0` as expected, but the FROM clause didn't include the MemberhipUsers table.

Also, I really had to struggle to learn about the `.indices` notation.  I found it by digging through the NHibernate source code, and saw that there's also `.elements` and some other dotted notations.  Where's a reference to the allowed syntax of an association path?  I feel like what's above is very close, and just missing something simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just trying to do this myself and it looks like this can be done with HQL but not the Criteria API.

https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-1795

To do it in HQL:

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/06/03/nhibernate-mapping-ndash-ltmapgt.aspx

Specifically look for Ayende's comment:

It is something like:
select 1 from Profile p join p.Entries e
where index(e) = 'HasCats' and e = 'true'